# Append all columns of dataframe to a new dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to append all columns of a dataframe to a new dataframe with single column.

My Current Dataframe:

```
|**namelist1**| **namelist2** |  **namelist3** |and so on
|khalid       |  sabbir       | liton          |
|tamim        |  sakib        | tawhid         |
|taskin       |  santo        | naim           |
```

Expected Dataframe:

```
**namelistall**
khalid      
sabbir     
liton
tamim       
sakib      
tawhid
taskin      
santo      
naim
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`numpy.ravel`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html) with DataFrame constructor:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'namelistall': np.ravel(df.to_numpy())})
print (df)
  namelistall
0      khalid
1      sabbir
2       liton
3       tamim
4       sakib
5      tawhid
6      taskin
7       santo
8        naim
```

Answer (score 0):

It creates a new dataframe with a single column by flattening the values of the original dataframe.

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame({'namelistall': current_df.values.ravel()})
```

Answer (score 0):

Even the stack() from pandas.DataFrame can be used.

The code to do so is as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'namelistall': current_df.stack().values})
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  namelistall
0      khalid
1      sabbir
2       liton
3       tamim
4       sakib
5      tawhid
6      taskin
7       santo
8        naim
```